# creating a queue message returns zero in id

Tags: c

I can't figure out what I missed. The first time that I run this `msgget() retuns 0` but `msgctl()` can remove it. The second time still having `0` and `msgctl()` aborts with invalid argument error.

Already tried to use some key instead of `IPC_PRIVATE`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DEBUG

int main(){
    int queue_id;

    if(queue_id = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0600) == -1){
         perror("queue");
         return -1;
    }

    if(msgctl(queue_id, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
         perror("queue rmid:");
    }

             return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` binds more tightly than `=`. Try putting parentheses around the assignment of `queue_id`, or put it on its own line:

```
queue_id = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0600);
if(queue_id == -1) {
         perror("queue");
         return -1;
}
```

Running your compiler with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` will help with this kind of thing.